# Autocomplete punctuation using grammar

Tags: parsing, autocomplete, antlr, grammar

I'm working on a tool that is able to autocomplete the necessary literals defined in a grammar. For example: in C# if a programmer enters: `for` with a space after it, then it's entirely possible to parse the code, determine that the programmer has started a `for` statement and autocomplete the necessary punctuation: `( ; ; )`.

The more I think about the problem, the more I think there must already be a solution for it, because it's such a common use case, but I can't find anything.

Is there a tool that can do this using a given grammar?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using ANTLR v3 instead of v4 you can use `Xtext` in order to generate an editor that features auto-complete and error-highlighting. This will happen in form of a plugin for eclipse and apparently also for IntelliJ IDEA.

If you want to use a different IDE or simply want to make use of ANTLR v4's powerfull features you could still have a look at the [Xtext Sources](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext) as they have to do what you are searching for in order to provide the above mentioned features properly...
[This](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-extras/tree/master/org.eclipse.xtext.generator/src/org/eclipse/xtext/generator) package looks very promising at first glance... You might find the respective code in there.
Be aware though that Xtext is mainly written with Xtend so you either have to do so as well or you have to rewrite it a bit

Comment: That's useful information. I'll look into it. Thank you! I'll mark this as the correct answer if I determine that this info can help to accomplish auto-completing constants/punctuation in the grammar.